# I have a long running process which I call in my Service Bus Queue. I want it to continue beyond 5 minutes

Tags: c#, azure, parallel-processing, azureservicebus

I have a long running process which performs matches between millions of records I call this code using a Service Bus, However when my process passes the 5 minute limit Azure starts processing the already processed records from the start again.

How can I avoid this

Here is my code:

```
private static async Task ProcessMessagesAsync(Message message, CancellationToken token)
 {
   long receivedMessageTrasactionId = 0;
   try
   {
     IQueueClient queueClient = new QueueClient(serviceBusConnectionString, serviceBusQueueName, ReceiveMode.PeekLock);

     // Process the message
     receivedMessageTrasactionId = Convert.ToInt64(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(message.Body));

     // My Very Long Running Method
     await DataCleanse.PerformDataCleanse(receivedMessageTrasactionId);
            //Get Transaction and Metric details

     await queueClient.CompleteAsync(message.SystemProperties.LockToken);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
     Log4NetErrorLogger(ex);
     throw ex;
   }
}
```

Comment: You can renew the lock and periodic intervals, via `message.RenewLock(); `

Comment: Thanks Brendan, What if I Use **ReceiveMode.ReceiveAndDelete** will it guarantee me that my process runs beyond 5 minutes?

Comment: Possibly - at the risk of potentially losing messages - your error handling and any retry mechanism will be more complex in that case.  A quick look at the documentation doesn't make it clear what the behavior of any timeouts are, but it'd be a pretty easy thing to test out and see how it goes...

Answer (score 3):

Messages are intended for notifications and not long running processing.

You've got a fewoptions:

1. Receive the message and rely on receiver's `RenewLock()` operation to extend the lock.
2. Use user-callback API and specify maximum processing time, if known, via [`MessageHandlerOptions.MaxAutoRenewDuration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.servicebus.messagehandleroptions?view=azure-dotnet) setting to auto-renew message's lock.
3. Record the processing started but do not complete the incoming message. Rather leverage [message deferral](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/message-deferral) feature, sending yourself a new delayed message with the reference to the deferred message `SequenceNumber`. This will allow you to periodically receive a "reminder" message to see if the work is finished. If it is, complete the deferred message by its `SequenceNumber`. Otherise, complete the "reminder" message along with sending a new one. This approach would require some level of your architecture redesign.
4. Similar to option 3, but offload processing to an external process that will report the status later. There are frameworks that can help you with that. MassTransit or NServiceBus. The latter has a [sample](https://docs.particular.net/samples/azure/azure-service-bus-long-running/) you can download and play with.

Note that option 1 and 2 are **not** guaranteed as those are client-side initiated operations.

Comment: Everything has pros and cons. Based on the requirements you'll decide what works better for your scenario.